# Cin.get() not working second time i use it

Tags: c++, menu, cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <strings.h>

using namespace std;

void encyclopedia()
{
int choice;
int choice2;

system("CLS");
cout << "Content Menu\n\n" 
     << "1. Gore\n\n"
     << "2. Wilson\n\n"
     << "3. Costa\n\n"
     << "Selection: ";
cin >> choice;
if (choice == 1)
{
           system("CLS");
           cout << "Al Gore's Book Summary of:\n\n"
                << "1. Introduction\n\n"
                << "2. \n\n"
                << "3. \n\n";
           cin >> choice2;
           if (choice2 == 1)
           {
                       system("CLS");
                      cout << "text here\n\n";
                      cout << "Press enter to continue\n";
                      cin.get();
                      encyclopedia();               
           }
           else if (choice2 == 2)
           {
                system("CLS");
                      cout << "text here\n\n";
                      cout << "Press enter to continue\n";
                      cin.get();
                      encyclopedia();               
           }
           else if (choice2 == 3)
           {
                system("CLS");
                      cout << "text here\n\n";
                      cout << "Press enter to continue\n";
                      cin.get();
                      encyclopedia();               
           }  
}
if (choice == 2)
{
           system("CLS");
           cout << "Wilson's Book Summary of:\n\n"
                << "1. Introduction\n\n"
                << "2. \n\n"
                << "3. \n\n";
           cin >> choice2;
           if (choice2 == 1)
           {
                       system("CLS");
                      cout << "text here\n\n";
                      cout << "Press enter to continue\n";
                      cin.get();
                      encyclopedia();               
           }
           else if (choice2 == 2)
           {
                system("CLS");
                      cout << "text here\n\n";
                      cout << "Press enter to continue\n";
                      cin.get();
                      encyclopedia();               
           }
           else if (choice2 == 3)
           {
                system("CLS");
                      cout << "text here\n\n";
                      cout << "Press enter to continue\n";
                      cin.get();
                      encyclopedia();               
           }  
}
if (choice == 3)
{
           system("CLS");
           cout << "Rebeca Costa's Book Summary of:\n\n"
                << "1. Introduction\n\n"
                << "2. \n\n"
                << "3. \n\n";
           cin >> choice;
           if (choice2 == 1)
           {
                       system("CLS");
                       cout << "text here\n\n";
                       cout << "Press enter to continue\n";
                       cin.get();
                       encyclopedia();               
           }
           else if (choice2 == 2)
           {
                       system("CLS");
                       cout << "text here\n\n";
                       cout << "Press enter to continue\n";
                       cin.get();
                       encyclopedia();               
           }
           else if (choice2 == 3)
           {
                      system("CLS");
                      cout << "text here\n\n";
                      cout << "Press enter to continue\n";
                      cin.get();
                      encyclopedia();               
           }  
}
}

int main()
{
cout << "2013 Written Task #2\n\nBy: Skye Leis\n\n";
cout << "Press enter to continue\n";
cin.get();
encyclopedia();   
}
```

While my first cin.get() is working, I cannot get the cin.get()'s before my encyclopedia() to work. When it runs, the first screen works, then the contents menu works, and the sub menus work, but on the parts it displays the actual text, it doesn't wait for a entry key before restarting the encyclopedia function.

Answer (score 1):

`cin` works on formatted input. Which means it will read up until it finds a blank space or a new line.

The problem is when you do

```
cin >> choice2;
```

When you enter a number and press enter, `cin` will read upto a `blank space`. Which means the `newline` (from key `enter`) is still on there. Your `cin.get` will read that new line character and continues.

In addition if I enter two numbers separated by space, your implementation will take the second number and use it for any of the next menu inputs.

To make sure that anything left on the input is read before you continue to the next menu item you can use `getline()`

```
string garbage;
cin >> choice2;
getline(cin, garbage);  // The will take care of any extra inputs.
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is there are still leftovers(endlines) so you might be getting some other unwanted chars after the user type, try adding:

```
cin.ignore( numeric_limits <streamsize> ::max(), '\n' );
```

after cin

Answer (score 0):

It reads last /n
and do:

> cin.clear(); cin.get();

or just write cin.get(); twice